# objective-c memory leaks?

Tags: objective-c

I have a question about the memory. According to the code & log below, is `0x6868190` a leak?

Code:

```
self.point = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"R"];
NSLog(@"********First********%d",[point retainCount]);
NSLog(@"********First********%p",point);
self.point = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A"];
NSLog(@"********Second********%d",[point retainCount]);
NSLog(@"********Second********%p",point);
```

Log:

```
 2012-04-17 20:27:49.838 test_[297:f803] ********First********2
 2012-04-17 20:27:49.838 test_[297:f803] ********First********0x6868190
 2012-04-17 20:27:49.839 test_[297:f803] ********Second********2
 2012-04-17 20:27:49.839 test_[297:f803] ********Second********0x6879500
```

Comment: Please add code formatting to your post.

Comment: If you are trying to understand memory management by logging retain counts, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @MikeWeller's comment cannot be overstated. Just forget about retain count, it does not do what you think it does. In the words of Apple's documentation: "it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Instruments to check for memory leak. The fact that the retain count isn't zero (or I guess you were expecting 1) doesn't necessarily mean there is a leak. Those objects will be released at the end of the run loop if necessary.

The stringWithFormat call creates an object with a retain count of 1 (which will be auto-released). Then your property is probably declared as retain/strong, which adds one that will be released when your main object is released. Therefore it is two.

Comment: Thank you for helping me! I have a further understanding of.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `retainCount` for checking memory leaks because inner implementation might alter it as you won't expect.

xcode has the proper tool for checking leaks so I advice you to use it.

Answer (score 1):

My website "[When to use retainCount?](http://whentouseretaincount.com/)" covers this. See questions seven and eight.

But in summary, no. Your variable is autoreleased so it's not leaking (unless you forget to release in `dealloc`).

Answer (score 0):

No. Those `NSString`s that are generated by the `NSString` class are `autorealeased`.